# php оператор эквивалентности

Tags: php

Учу PHP. В учебнике пишется что пустая строка "" и число "0" равны, то есть сравнение `==` должно давать 1.
Почему, когда я запускаю этот код

```
$num="0";
$string="";
$bool=$string==$num;
echo "($string==$num)=$bool";
```

браузер не пишет 1, то есть не считает его эквивалентным? А автор показывает что результат у него 1. У кого ошибка?

Comment: 1) почему кавычки в выводе? 2) если убрать кавычки, то почему в `($string==$num)=$bool` вы присваиваете выражению `($string==$num)` значение `$bool`? Там должен быть знак `==`

Comment: Посмотрите в первоисточник http://php.net/manual/ru/types.comparisons.php Таблица `Гибкое сравнение с помощью ==`

Comment: @BOPOH, это строка. там только переменные подставляются, но не вычисляются выражения.

Comment: это пример того, когда пустая строка может быть эквивалентна числу в php. затем идет пример тот же самый, только с оператором ===, когда проверяются и типы значений. у меня что ==, что ===, все в браузере выводится как false.

Comment: У вас нет строгого сравнения с помощью ===.

Comment: @Visman, а, понял что хотели показать. Тогда надо было: `echo sprintf('($string==$num)=%s', $bool);`

Comment: @sandy, а где вы это прочитали? Может имелось ввиду `$num=0;`? Сравните вывод: `var_dump(array('0' == 0,'0' == '',0 == '',));` ))

Comment: да, я уже понял. кавычки в $num=0 лишние..

Comment: @sandy, строго говоря `==` это оператор _равенства_. А вот `===` -- оператор _эквивалентности_.

Answer (score 1):

Самое удивительное в этом вопросе - это четыре голоса за закрытие.
А сам вопрос - интересный и весьма важный для понимания того, как работает сравнение в пхп.

Как написано в мануале, "Если сравниваются строки, и обе могут быть приведены к числам, то они приводятся, и сравниваются как числа".

Здесь же мы имеем только одну строку с числом, и в этом случае РНР не приводит операнды к числам, и сравнивает две строки как строки.

Пример же в учебнике касается сравнения переменных разных типов - числа и строки. При котором **любая** строка, не приводящаяся к числу, будет приравнена к нулю (а не только пустая):

```
echo "(0=='PHP')=".json_encode(0=="PHP");
```

А вот что, скорее всего, *имелось в виду* в учебнике - это что и `0` и `""` приравниваются к `FALSE` в операторах, требующих булев аргумент.

**Мораль:** учебник выкинуть и читать мануал.

Comment: Голоса за закрытие появились потому, что вопрос в текущей постановке вызван опечаткой автора (лишние ковычки у `$num="0";`). А для того, чтобы вопрос действительно стал полезным сообществу, его имеет смысл изменить, акцентировав внимание на сравнении переменных